# Resetting fileInput in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have been trying for a long time to reset `fileInput` in a Shiny app and read solutions to similar problems, but my problem still persists. Most solutions ultimately lead to using Dean Attali's brilliant `shinyjs` package and the `reset()` function therein. Here's what my code looks like after following [these](https://gist.github.com/bborgesr/07406b30ade8a011e59971835bf6c6f7) instructions:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs) 
library(xlsx) 
library(tidyverse) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fileInput('inFile', 'Choose file'),
  actionButton('reset', 'Reset'),
  radioButtons("type","Choose file type",choices = c('csv','xls')),
  tableOutput('tbl')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  observe({
    req(input$inFile)
    if(input$type=='csv'){
      rv$data <- read.csv(input$inFile$datapath)
    }
    if(input$type=='xls'){
      rv$data <- read_excel(input$inFile$datapath)
    }

  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv$data <- NULL
    reset('inFile')
  })

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    rv$data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I initially select the `csv` option and am able to load a csv file. Now when I press the reset button, it clears the data. As soon as I select the `xls` option, I get an error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4135
Warning: Error in : Unknown file extension: csv
```

Which makes me believe that `input$inFile$datapath` still contains the pathname of the csv file that I selected earlier. I have run out of ideas on how to solve this problem and would greatly appreciate some help please.

Comment: Do you have `xlsx` package installed?

Comment: @Aaghaz Hussain Yes I do.

Comment: Is it loaded, which is not shown in the code.

Comment: It is loaded too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ideally `fileInput` would properly reset, but you can do this as a workaround. Add an explicit flag variable (`rv$clear`) to indicate whether you're in cleared state, and toggle that on and off in high-priority observers when reset and upload occur, respectively.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs) 
library(xlsx) 
library(tidyverse) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fileInput('inFile', 'Choose file'),
  actionButton('reset', 'Reset'),
  radioButtons("type","Choose file type",choices = c('csv','xls')),
  tableOutput('tbl')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(
    data = NULL,
    clear = FALSE
  )

  observe({
    req(input$inFile)
    req(!rv$clear)

    if(input$type=='csv'){
      rv$data <- read.csv(input$inFile$datapath)
    }
    if(input$type=='xls'){
      rv$data <- read_excel(input$inFile$datapath)
    }

  })

  observeEvent(input$inFile, {
    rv$clear <- FALSE
  }, priority = 1000)

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv$data <- NULL
    rv$clear <- TRUE
    reset('inFile')
  }, priority = 1000)

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    rv$data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```